# How to set up my Django view to GET an external API

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

trying to set up my Django Rest View to properly pass an external API call.

```
class BucketData(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs): 
            external_api_url = "http://localhost:3000/security?select=symbol,company" 
            res = urllib.urlopen(external_api_url).read()
            data = json.loads(res)
            print(data)
            return Response(data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

This doesn't seem to work and I get a: `{ "detail": "Not found." }` error when I test out the URL:

api url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('bucket-data/', BucketData.as_view(), name='bucket-data')
]
```

The localhost:3000 API works, I've tested it using curl, and as well using django shell using the `requests` library. Also, the data avaiable through localhost:3000 is already packaged in JSON.

How can I solve my error? Been trying to for a couple of days and I don't think I'm close.

Answer (score 0):

If it is working in your django sheel using `requests`, why are you not using it here ?

```
import requests

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs): 
        external_api_url = "http://localhost:3000/security?select=symbol,company" 
        response = requests.get(external_api_url)
        data = json.loads(response)
        print(data)
        return Response(data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

EDIT after your comment :
I think the problem is with the APPEND_SLASH : is it set to True in your config ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#append-slash

Comment: I wasn’t able to get it to work with requests originally, let me get back to you and test it again when I’m infront of my PC.

Comment: I just tried your format, still getting the same error, GET 404, `Not Found: /api/bucket-data/`. The URL path clearly exists according to swagger and other path checkers.

Comment: Ok I see : in your question, I understood the problem was with the url in the `get` definition. But it is not linked to the way you wrote `get`, it is linked to the way you define the url linked to the view `BucketData `

Comment: Henri, it should be set to True as I didn't touch the default. Either way I added the slash at the end of the localhost request and I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found out the error:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('bucket-data', BucketData.as_view(), name='bucket-data')
]
```

I had to remove the last slash from my URL path. Not sure why however. Sorry I'm not able to explain more but hope this help you in the future.